# How to tell Devise to render it's views in another layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Devise keeps on rendering it's login form in the default `views/layouts/application.html.erb` layout, but I want it to use the Administrate layout, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case this applies:

> To have Devise use a separate layout to the rest of your application,
>   you could do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "layout_name_for_devise"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

**SOURCE**: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts

Comment: Thanks, I think it does render in the correct layout now, but it does't find now the templates thats were in that layout.
 
`Missing partial user/sessions/_stylesheet, devise/sessions/_stylesheet, devise/_stylesheet, application/_stylesheet with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution-1:**

Overide devise `SessionsController` with your custom session controller and set `layout: :adminstrator`

**Solution-2**

In `ApplicationController`:

```
layout: custom_layout

def custom_layout
    params[:controller] == "sessions" ? "adminstrator" : "application"
end
```

Hope it helps!